# how to format date in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, momentjs

I am using [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and I have multiple columns with dates, the current data is in this format `2020-06-18 14:32:45.707` and I want to format it and display it as `18/06/2020 14.32`.

I applied [datetime](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime) plugin in DataTables, but still can't make it work.

Currently I am using :

```js
render: function(data) {
  return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
}
```

Which is working fine. But I want to use render:

```js
render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

I have included [moment.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js) and [datetime.js](https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/dataRender/datetime.js) as the [documentation](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/datetime) says and I should apply:

```js
$.fn.dataTable.render.moment(to);
```

My dates are shown as 'invalid date' in my table when i use this method. 
below is a demo.

Could you please explain me what am I doing wrong with?:

```js
$.fn.dataTable.render.moment('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

I have the other method working, but I want to learn from my mistakes as I spend much time investigating and couldn't figure out the issue. Thank you very much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
      //render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm' )
      "render": function(data) {
        return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
      },
      "targets": 1
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/dataRender/datetime.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>date before format</th>
      <th>date after format</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2020-06-18 14:32:45.707</td>
      <td>2020-06-18 14:32:45.707</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I do not think you can in-line the function without providing a callback?

Comment: If you only use this `$.fn.dataTable.render.moment(to);`, then it assumes the "from" date is already formatted as an ISO 8601 datetime. But your source data is this: `2020-06-18 14:32:45.707` - which is not an ISO 8601 date time (there is no `T` between the date and the time). So use the `$.fn.dataTable.render.moment( from, to );` form instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```js
// Argument shifting
if (arguments.length === 1) {
  locale = 'en';
  to = from;
  from = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
}
```

The default FROM is `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, you need to specify YOUR source format.

```js
const FROM_PATTERN = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS';
const TO_PATTERN   = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm';

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      render: $.fn.dataTable.render.moment(FROM_PATTERN, TO_PATTERN),
      targets: 1
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/dataRender/datetime.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>date before format</th>
      <th>date after format</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2020-06-18 14:32:45.707</td>
      <td>2020-06-18 14:32:45.707</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you very much. I understood the issue now. much appreciated.

Comment: If the date from is microsoft json date `/Date(1515351600000)/`, how do we set `FROM_PATTERN`?

Comment: @Willy M$ date is archaic You will need to pre-process the date, before formatting. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2316066

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 columns, the following code working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: [1,2], render: DataTable.render.datetime('M/DD/YYYY')
    }]
  });
});
```